# metalinguistic use of "many"

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

In the following dialogue, is B's use of "many" a metalinguistic one?

> A: "Were there many there?"

> B: "Many"! There were more than "many" - the whole place was heaving - you could hardly breathe!"

Comment: "Metalinguistic"!  Some dictionaries don't even have an entry for it!

Comment: See my answer here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/460367/why-is-it-unnatural-to-say-he-is-as-clever-as-rude/612829#612829

Answer (score 0):

No, I wouldn't say it was metalinguistic at all. There is nothing being conveyed by that word that cannot be understood on a linguistic level alone.

'B' is simply making an exclamation over 'A's use of the word '*many*', suggesting that it is inadequate to convey the vast number of people there.

If it had been written with a question mark rather than an exclamation you would probably have seen it as rhetorical, repeating the question before answering which is very common in speech. In a way, that is what 'B' is doing - but using an exclamation mark conveys the emphasis that would have come over in spoken English.